# Python Geocoders Not Working

Tags: python, django, geocoding, connectionexception

I am trying to access geolocation of addresses input by the User in my Django App.

The App was working fine with pygeocoder. Suddenly, the app has started giving problems.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ishaan/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygeocoder.py", line 129, in geocode
    return GeocoderResult(Geocoder.get_data(params=params))
  File "/home/ishaan/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygeocoder.py", line 204, in get_data
    response = session.send(request.prepare())
  File "/home/ishaan/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ishaan/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/ishaan/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/home/ishaan/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 344, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=conn.timeout)
  File "/home/ishaan/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 314, in _raise_timeout
    if 'timed out' in str(err) or 'did not complete (read)' in str(err):  # Python 2.6
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type Error)
```

I am unable to unserstand this problem, and have a close to no knowledge about SSL and its errors.

I dont know, how relevant it is, but the app was working until I installed  Redis Server for another app in the same project. I have uninstalled it, but it is still not working.

Lastly, No other Geocoder is working - Every geocoder gives the same error. I tried to use GeoPy, geocoder 1.6.4

Thanks in advance